# How to allow auto connect to microphone through web application on chrome without messages

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, browser, twilio

I have recently been developing twilio web application. My application can receive calls. This feature is OK. But When answer button is clicked, message pops up "localhost want to use microphone". I want to avoid this message. I want to answer call once when answer button is clicked without any messages. Is it possible? if possible how can I do it?

Comment: I think for security reasons this is not possible.

Comment: This is os specific, i guess that comes from windows OS _(guessed)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, the browser won't allow using microphone without asking the user. [Chrome can be only set to ask for permission or always deny.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en)

You can set [an exception for these rules,](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3123708) but it will only affect your own browser. Other users will still have to allow microphone access when they open your site.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

The request to access local sytem devices is a security feature built into the browser.  If your website is being loaded over HTTP then the browser will prompt the user for access every time they load the page.  If the site is loaded over HTTPS, then most browsers will automatically remember the authorization or allow the use to specify they want the authorization remembered.

Hope that helps.